# Embedded Jetty cannot resolve jstl core

Tags: jsp, jetty, jstl, embedded-jetty

I have been trying different things for the past few days and I still haven't managed to get this to work.

I am trying to create a jar with embedded jetty that can be run `java -jar MyApp.jar`. Servlets work and a jsp file without the taglib line will work just fine, otherwise I get a 500 Server not found error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = "hello.App"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'hello.App'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'hello.App'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it :zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def jettyVersion = '9.4.5.v20170502'
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: jettyVersion
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlets', version: jettyVersion
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-annotations', version: jettyVersion
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'apache-jsp', version: jettyVersion
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'apache-jstl', version: jettyVersion

    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.2'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.7'
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hello.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

*JettyServer.java*

```
package hello.jetty;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class JettyServer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JettyServer.class);

    public static final String WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION = "webapp";
    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT_START = 8080;
    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT_STOP = 8090;
    private final int startPort;
    private final int stopPort;

    public JettyServer() {
        this(DEFAULT_PORT_START, DEFAULT_PORT_STOP);
    }

    public JettyServer(int startPort, int stopPort) {
        this.startPort = startPort;
        this.stopPort = stopPort;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(startPort);
        WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

        root.setContextPath("/");
        root.setDescriptor(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");

        URL webAppDir = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION);
        if (webAppDir == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No %s directory was found in the JAR file", WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION));
        }

        root.setResourceBase(webAppDir.toURI().toString());
        root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        //Enable JSP & JSTL support
        Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
        classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
        classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
        root.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$" );

        server.setHandler(root);
        server.start();

        log.info("Jetty server started");
        log.debug("Jetty web server port: {}", startPort);
        log.debug("Port to stop Jetty with the 'stop' operation: {}", stopPort);

        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(stopPort, new Server[]{server});
        monitor.start();

        server.join();

        log.info("Jetty server exited");
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop(DEFAULT_PORT_STOP);
    }

    public void stop(Integer stopPort) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), stopPort);
            log.info("Jetty stopping...");
            s.setSoLinger(false, 0);
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            out.write(("stop\r\n").getBytes());
            out.flush();
            s.close();
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            log.info("Jetty not running!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JettyServer jettyServer = new JettyServer();
        jettyServer.start();
    }
}
```

*index.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <%= new java.util.Date() %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <c:out var="${1+2}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get jetty to display the index.jsp file?

**UPDATE:** Here are the jar files that gradle pulls in:

```
jetty-webapp-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-servlets-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-annotations-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
apache-jsp-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
apache-jstl-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
jetty-xml-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-servlet-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-continuation-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-http-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-util-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-io-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-plus-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
asm-5.1.jar
asm-commons-5.1.jar
jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
apache-jsp-8.5.9.1.jar
ecj-4.4.2.jar
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
logback-core-1.1.2.jar
jetty-security-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
jetty-jndi-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
asm-tree-5.1.jar
apache-el-8.5.9.1.jar
jetty-server-9.4.5.v20170502.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
```

While reading through this I noticed apache-jsp in there twice with two different versions. Could having duplicate jars be my problem? If so, how do I get gradle to exclude one of them?

Comment: Please list your resolved dependencies (what does gradle think your complete list of dependencies looks like?)

Comment: @Joakim I have added the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't duplicate jars, they are 2 different jars with different group ids: one from org.eclipse.jetty and one from org.mortbay.jasper.

I assume your fat jar contains all the classes etc that have been unpacked from the dependent jars. Therefore, you're going to have to add a pattern to the org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern that refers to the location of these classes inside the jar: normally that pattern contains a list of patterns of jar file names to examine for tlds, but in your case the tlds aren't contained in jar files. Furthermore, I'd double check if the classloader is a URLClassloader: jetty walks the classloader hierarchy looking for URLClassLoaders that it should interrogate and match the patterns against.

Finally, IIWY, I wouldn't do it this way :)  I would pre-compile all my jsps and simply pack them into your fat jar, that way you eliminate all problems of on-the-fly discovery and compilation.

Comment: If I go for pre-compiling the jsps, what needs to change to make that happen? I'm guessing something will need to be added to build.gradle to do the compilation. Does anything need to change in JettyServer?